# VS 2015 Error:The WiX Toolset v4 build tools must be installed to build this project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wix

I have **VS 2015** and I have installed **Wix v3.10** but when I try to build the setup project it shows me this error:

> The WiX Toolset v4 build tools must be installed to build this project.

I don't want to install wix v4 because it's not stable yet.

How I can get rid of this error?

Answer (score 9):

Had this error too with VS2017 and WiX 3.11.

I had added WiX Toolset v4 Setup Project as a new project in my solution instead of WiX Toolset v3 Setup Project. I kept getting the same error upon build.

So I added a WiX Toolset v3 Setup Project to the solution and *deleted the WiX Toolset v4 Setup Project (the error remained until I deleted WiX Toolset v4 Setup Project).

Now the error is gone, the build works and my Installer works. Is this the same problem on your side? Here's a screenshot that might help illustrate: [Add New Project window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlrdg.png)

Comment: Thanks for this. I find it silly that WiX toolset 3.11 even offers a v4 setup project.

Answer (score 0):

I created an .EXE with WiX 3.x (I forgot its version) in VS2012.

Then, I installed VS 2013 (I installed WiX 3.10). The same error occurred. Then I copied the contents from `yourProduct.wixproj` from the previous version of my Wix project to the newer version, no error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Visual Studio 2017, I was using Wix 3.11 with V4 project from the Visual Studio project template and so this problem occurred.

I removed the v4 project and selected the v3 project template. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by installing **WiX Toolset build tools**

Faced the same issue. In my case, I had installed VS2017 extension of WIX and thought it was sufficient. But, **WiX Toolset build tools** must be installed to trigger the build from VS which means the extension needs WiX Toolset build tools.